# C fread parameter type mismatch

Tags: c

Im trying to write some numbers into an array by passing main the argument

> ./test numbers 100

on the command line, but i get an error in fread of parameter type mismatch for argv[1]. Isnt the 4th argument in fread the name of the file. Don't i get that from argv[1] (numbers)?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i=0; i<*argv[2]; ++i)
        fread(&array[i],sizeof(int),1,argv[1]);
}
```

Edit: Fixed the problem of it printing to the terminal. It had something to do with the make file.

Comment: the 4th parameter to fread is a file pointer, not a file name.  I.E. need to open the file with: FILE * fp = fopen( argv[1], "r" );   Then check that fp is not NULL.   then if( 1 != fread(&array[i], sizeof(int), 1, fp ) ) {// handle error }  BTW: how is 'array' defined?

Comment: @user3629249 dynamically , int *array = (int*)malloc(atoi(argv[2]) * sizeof(int));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fourth argument of [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) is file descriptor and **not** file name.

> size_t fread( void          *buffer, size_t size, size_t count,
>                 FILE          *stream ); /* (until C99) */
> size_t fread( void *restrict buffer, size_t size, size_t count, 
>                 FILE *restrict stream );  /* (since C99) */

Use the following:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");  /* Open the file */

if(fp) for(int i=0; i<*argv[2]; ++i) {
  fread(&array[i],sizeof(int),1, fp);  /* Read */
}

if(fp) fclose(fp);  /* Close */
```

Or even more efficient way, to read all integers at once, use:

```
number_of_ints_read = fread(array, sizeof(int), atoi(argv[2]), fp);
/* array[0] to arrau[number_of_ints_read-1] are read */
```

Expected argument type is `FILE *` but you pass `char *` and thus the type mismatch.

You may also want to revisit the condition `i<*argv[2]`, you possibly want `i < atoi(argv[2])` or similar. (You need to include `stdlib.h` for `atoi`)

This will read file as raw data data. If you file contains number in textual format, you need to use formatted IO (`fscanf` for example).

Comment: just to clarify, will this code only read up to 100 integers, even if theres more in the file?

Comment: Yes, this would read one integer per iteration. So even if there are more integers it will read only 100 integers. If you want to read `int`s from a text file, you need to use formatted IO.

Comment: As written (`i < *argv[2]`), the code will read up to 49 lines, because the character code for `1` is 49 in the ASCII and 8859-1 and related code sets.  To treat the `argv[2]` as 100, you need to convert it from a string to a number, probably with `atoi()`, doing it once before the start of the loop.  I can imagine worse code layouts than the code shown in the answer, but there aren't many of them.  Please use an orthodox code layout.

Comment: does fread automatically print to the terminal, when i run this it prints out all the numbers

Comment: @user3593148 No, it does not. You need to explicitly print the numbers.

Comment: @MohitJain thats what i would like, but even when i take everything out of main, it still prints all the numbers.

Comment: @user3593148 You need to use the debugger to spot which line causes those prints. For instance you can try the example code given at http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread